# How to save multiline text in html text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text-editor, droidscript

Im creating a text editor in html and jquery with droidscript .

the problem is when i try to save multy line text , the text saved as one line
this is save function :

```
function save(file){
    text = $("#editor").text();
app.WriteFile(file,text);
}
```

- i take the text from `<div>` with `contenteditable` .
- `app.WriteFile()` is droidscript function use to save text in files .

Comment: Replace `text = $("#editor").text();` with `text = $("#editor")[0].innerText;`

Comment: it work . thank you .